# AngularJS - Javascript number of days between two dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two dates that I get in the following format - that are returned from a web service:

```
var dateone = "2016-08-21T07:00:00.000Z";
var datetwo = "2016-08-28T07:00:00.000Z";
var datediff = datetwo - dateone;
var numdays = Math.round(datediff);
console.log("Number of Days is " + numdays);
```

I get `NaN`.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `dateone` and `datetwo` variables are `String`s not `Date`s.
Try this:

```
var dateone = new Date("2016-08-21T07:00:00.000Z"); 
var datetwo = new Date("2016-08-28T07:00:00.000Z");
```

Also, substracting 2 `Date`s objects will give you the difference between them in milliseconds, if you want to determine the number of days, you can do something like this:

```
var dayDif = (datetwo - dateone)  / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.   Do you know if I can do the math at presentation layer in AngularJS if I have {{dateone}} and {{datetwo}}

Comment: @JotiBasi Yes, you should be able to do the calculation in HTML {{(datetwo - dateone)  / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24}} this should work.

Comment: @Titus I can not do arithmetic operation directly to your dateone & datetwo objects.                                                                                       var timeDiff = Math.abs(datetwo.getTime() - dateone.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));                console.log("<<<<<<< diffDays >>>>>>>>.", diffDays);                         This works for me. I think this will help.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do with moment.js

```
var a = moment('2016-08-21T07:00:00.000Z');
var b = moment('2016-08-28T07:00:00.000Z'); 
var days = b.diff(a, 'days');
```

[`JsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/wL2f7q0w/112/)

Answer (score 1):

```
let invitedDate = '2019-11-27T05:19:23.32';
let deference = new Date().getTime() - new Date(invitedDate).getTime();
let days = Math.round(Math.abs(deference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
```

if you need to get the deference between 2 different days what can do is, get using Date.getTime() and the invited Date example as above calculate the Days

Comment: answers without explanation are marked as low quality... can you add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

As well as what Titus said about turning them into Dates rather than Strings, try something like this:

```
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // Calculates milliseconds in a day
var diffDays = Math.abs((dateone.getTime() - datetwo.getTime())/(oneDay));
```

I don't know what you expected Math.round() to do for you, but I don't see that helping much. Math.abs() ensures that the difference is positive, while subtracting the two getTime() functions gets the difference in milliseconds.

Hope this helps.